# Why is this derivation of the mean of the gamma distribution using the log-partition function incorrect?

Tags: probability, distributions, mean, gamma-distribution, exponential-family

I am using this formulation of the exponential family :
$$
\large f_{X}(x;\boldsymbol{\eta})=h(x) \exp \left(\boldsymbol{\eta} \cdot \mathbf{T}(x)-A(\boldsymbol{\eta})\right)
$$
The gamma distribution is given as :
$$
\large f _{X}(x\,;\alpha, \beta) = \frac{{\beta^{\alpha} x ^{\alpha - 1}\exp(-\beta x)}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}
$$
Doing some algebraic manipulations on this PDF, we can show that :
$$
\boldsymbol{\eta} = \begin{bmatrix} \eta _{1} \\ \eta _{2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha - 1 \\ -\beta \end{bmatrix}
$$
Similarly for the log partition function :
$$
A(\boldsymbol{\eta}) = \ln(\Gamma(\eta _{1} + 1)) - (\eta _{1} + 1)\ln(-\eta _{2})
$$
Now the mean of the distribution should be calculated as follows :
$$
\boldsymbol{\mu} = \nabla _{\boldsymbol{\eta}} A(\boldsymbol{\eta})
$$
Further calculating, the "mean vector" can be found to be :
$$
\boldsymbol{\mu} = \begin{bmatrix}\psi(\alpha) - \ln(\beta) \\ \alpha / \beta \end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $\psi$ is the digamma function.

However, this implies that the mean of the gamma distribution will be a two dimensional vector which is blatantly not the case!
Can anyone point out what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\boldsymbol{\mu}$ is not the expected value of an exponential family distribution. It is [the expected value of the distribution's sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Differential_identities_for_cumulants) $\mathbf{T}(X)$.
For a $\mathop{\mathrm{Gamma}}\left(\alpha, \beta\right)$-distributed random variable $X$ we have $\mathbf{T}(X) = \left(\ln\left(X\right), X\right)^\top$ and hence $\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X\right) = \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 = \alpha/\beta$.

Comment: So is $\boldsymbol \mu$ not the mean then? Moreover, is the mean defined to be the expectation of the sufficient statistic or the expectation of the random variable?

Comment: @SagnikTaraphdar $\boldsymbol \mu$ is the mean of $\mathbf T(X)$. The terms "mean" and "expected value" of a random variable are synonymous. The mean of a distribution $\mathbb P$ is defined as the expected value of a $\mathbb P$-distributed random variable. For a real-valued random variable $X$ with probability density function  $f_X$ (w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure) it is given by $\int_{\mathbb R} x f_X(x) \, \mathrm dx$.

Comment: I understand that but my only remaining query was this : is the mean of the sufficient statistic, here denoted as $\mathbf \mu$ , *not* the same as the mean of the distribution?

Comment: @SagnikTaraphdar $\boldsymbol \mu = \mathbb E[\mathbf T(X)] = \mathbb E[\left(\ln\left(X\right), X\right)^\top] = (\mathbb E[\ln(X)], \mathbb E[X])^\top$. But the mean of a $\mathop{\mathrm{Gamma}}\left(\alpha, \beta\right)$ distribution is the expected value of a $\mathop{\mathrm{Gamma}}\left(\alpha, \beta\right)$-distributed random variable $X$, i.e. $\mathbb E[X]$. Clearly, $(\mathbb E[\ln(X)], \mathbb E[X])^\top$ and $\mathbb E[X]$ are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I was just confused as to how the mean of the distribution was related to the log-partition function. I didn't realize it was actually the mean of the sufficient statistic that's related to the log-partition function.

Comment: @SagnikTaraphdar I'm glad I could help!